# How to Start resque workers through Chef cookbook?

Tags: chef-infra, resque, chef-recipe, cookbook

I am a newbie to Chef and I want to restart resque workers on a cloud node after every deployment through my recipe. There is a Rake task which resque provides to start the workers

```
QUEUE='*' bundle exec rake environment resque:work >>/log/resque.log 2>&1 &
```

to stop it, I grep the resque process and manually kill it.

I was not able to find any good examples on how to run rake tasks in Chef [services](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_service.html). Can someone help me with a sample service which will do what I intend to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `execute` resource with `action :nothing` that will be used to restart the workers (adapt as necessary):

```
execute "restart_resque_workers" do
  command "pkill resque && QUEUE='*' bundle exec rake environment resque:work >>/log/resque.log 2>&1 &"
  cwd "/path/to/app"
  action :nothing
end
```

Then, on the deployment resource, add:

```
application "app" do
  ...
  notifies :run, "execute[restart_resque_workers]"
end
```

Ideally, the `stop`, `start` and `restart` mechanism would be handled by a proper service, but in any case the overall pattern is the same.

The `notifies` attribute will only kick in if the `application` resource is modified (usually that means a new deployment).

More information on notifications [in the Chef docs](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/resources.html#notifications).

---

A poor man's service could go like this:

```
service 'resque_workers' do
  start = "QUEUE='*' bundle exec rake environment resque:work >>/log/resque.log 2>&1"
  stop = "pkill resque"
  start_command start
  stop_command stop
  restart_command "#{stop}; #{start}"
  supports [ :start, :stop, :restart ]
end
```

Then use `notifies :restart, "service[resque_workers]"` in the `application` resource.

Comment: Thanks for writing the service out.. :)

Comment: NP! I had just done something similar for one of my cookbooks, so I put it here. :) Note that this is not an actual service that you can manage on the OS using `service rescue_workers start/stop`. If for any reason you need to manage it on the box itself, you'll still need to run the commands yourself.